# Initialize private array with curl parentheses

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to use curl parentheses to initialize in my constructor, but I get an error. Can anyone help me to use this way to initialize my array ? Thanks.

**CODE:**

Here is my private member

`private:
    bool arr[50];`

and this is my constructor

`void Constructor()
{
    arr = {}; // As usual, I should get an array full of false.
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() : arr{} // or Foo() : arr() {} in C++03
  {}

  bool arr[20];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I have used this way and I get an error.

Comment: @CYB then either you are trying the C++11 way and your compiler doesn't support it, or you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and it's C++11. How can I modify in other way?

Comment: @CYB See the comment in the code in my answer. You need round braces.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't show errors on initialization line but I got error in my constructor body ..

Comment: @CYB What errors? What are you trying to do? What I have shown is how to initialize the array.

Comment: `Foo()
    : arr () {}
 { // <- get error C2447 at this line
   // like this way
 }`

Comment: Oops ..... I found I misunderstand what you said, so I got C2447. I only use round braces to initialize it, then correct. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support all C++11 yet.. check the feature is supported.

Comment: I've googled this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx#fbid=14dSLirvDCb